# a simple rails 3.1 view using group_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, group-by

I have a menu on a site I am working on, menu of food_items. Each of the records in the table also contains a field of category. This category can be burgers, munchies, drinks, or anything else they want to categorize food items by.

I am trying to display the menu, with items grouped by this category field. My attempt so far:

```
food_item_menus_controller.rb
...
def food_list
  @foods = FoodItem.all
  @food_list = @foods.group_by { |t| t.category }
end


views/food_item_menus/index.html.haml
= @food_list.group_by (@food_items.category).each do |food_list|
  %p
    = food_list.name
  %ul
    -  for food_items in food_items
      %li
        = food_items.name
```

My error is that I have a nil object. I guess my call to @foods isn't returning anything.

```
models/food_item.rb
class FoodItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menus, :through => :food_item_menus
  has_many :food_item_menus
end
```

Did I set up something wrong? Or is my thinking wrong that if I call @foods in the view, it's not actually calling the variable I set in the controller? The more I try to figure this out, the more I am just getting confused about everything, including the basics.

Comment: Just FYI, you don't "call" `@foods`, you "reference" it. You call methods. You can verify if `FoodItem.all` returns what you expect using `rails c` (console). `@foods.each do |category|` is odd, because each object will actually be a `FoodItem`, not a category.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. I changed some of the code, I understand what you mean. so now I am getting an: undefined method `category' for nil:NilClass error. So perhaps I don't understand the argument, how to tell the group_by function to use the category field in the table? it's not table.field way?

Answer (score 2):

Your view code is full of errors, it should be something like this:

```
= @food_list.each do |category, food_items|
  %p
    = category
  %ul
    - food_items.each do |food|
      %li
        = food.name
```

Breakdown of errors:

- `@food_list.group_by(@food_items.category).each do |food_list|`
   - you haven't assigned a value to `@food_items` anywhere; `@food_list` is assigned as the result from a `group_by` call in your controller, so here you're calling it twice; `group_by` returns a hash, so your each block should have two arguments, not one.
- `for food_items in food_items` - using the same variable name for the iterated variable and the iterator; `food_items` is not assigned a value anywhere.

Comment: it makes sense but i still get a nil error. You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each   https://gist.github.com/1344406

Comment: @Chad Your view is named `index`, but your controller action method is named `food_list`. This controller method should probably renamed to `index`.

Comment: Also, the first line should start with a `-`, not `=`. I missed this when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a scope on the model, instead.

```
class FoodItem
    scope :categorized, -> { group(:category) }
end
```

**references**
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html