# Filtering products in Index of Categories & Products by Product's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, nested, filtering, has-many

Product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :categories, through: :product_categories
has_many :product_categories, dependent: :destroy
```

Category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_categories

  has_many :products, through: :product_categories
  has_many :product_categories, dependent: :destroy

  default_scope :order => 'id'
end
```

static_pages_controller.rb

```
...

def catalog
  @categories = Category.all

  render layout: "catalog"
end
```

My View:

```
// uses tabbable navigation from bootstrap to iterate over the categories, then it iterates over each product and inserts them into .tab-content

    .row-fluid
      .span8.offset2
        .tabbable
          %ul.nav.nav-tabs
            %li.active
              %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#tab-#{@categories.first.id}"} #{@categories.first.name}
            - @categories.each do |category|
              -unless category == @categories.first
                %li
                  %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#tab-#{category.id}"} #{category.name}
          .tab-content
            .tab-pane.fade.in.active{id: "tab-#{@categories.first.id}"}
              %h3.center #{@categories.first.name}
              %hr
              - if @categories.first.products.count == 0
                .span6.offset3
                  This category is empty.
              -else
                - @categories.first.products.each do |product|
                  = render 'product', :product => product
            - @categories.each do |category|
              -unless category == @categories.first
                .tab-pane.fade{id: "tab-#{category.id}"}
                  %h3.center #{category.name}
                  %hr
                  - if category.products.count == 0
                    .span6.offset3
                      This category is empty.
                  -else
                    - category.products.each do |product|
                      = render 'product', :product => product
```

**Currently it shows every product that is in a category. I would like it to only show products where :status => "published".** I just can't seem to figure out how to approach this, in the controller? tired and not very familar at SQL query syntax. So pardon my ignorance :P

Comment: @categories = Category.joins(:products).where('products.status' => "published") -- am I on to something? _I get duplicated category names using this._

Comment: Check this post if it helps you to solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031317/a-simple-rails-3-1-view-using-group-by

Need to group by category and display products in it

Comment: Got it fixed, I'll post what I did after I'm finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gemfile

```
gem 'squeel'
```

category.rb

```
scope :with_published_products, -> { joins{product_categories.product}.where{products.status.eq "published"}.uniq }
```

static_pages_controller.rb

```
def catalog
  @categories = Category.with_published_products
end
```

my view

```
- @categories.each do |category|
  category.name
  category.products.each do |product
    = render 'product', :product => product
```

Hope this helps someone else... :)